# Parse XML in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2016

I have

```
INSERT INTO [PubMed.Author] (pmid, ValidYN, LastName, FirstName, ForeName, Suffix, Initials, Affiliation)
    SELECT
        pmid, 
        nref.value('@ValidYN', 'varchar(max)') ValidYN, 
        nref.value('LastName[1]', 'varchar(max)') LastName, 
        nref.value('FirstName[1]', 'varchar(max)') FirstName,
        nref.value('ForeName[1]', 'varchar(max)') ForeName,
        nref.value('Suffix[1]', 'varchar(max)') Suffix,
        nref.value('Initials[1]', 'varchar(max)') Initials,
        nref.value('Affiliation[1]', 'varchar(max)') Affiliation
    FROM
        [Publication.PubMed.XML] 
    CROSS APPLY
        XMLData.nodes('//AuthorList/Author') AS R(nref)
    WHERE
        pmid = @pmid
```

And it used to work fine when PubMed only listed one affiliation like

```
<Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ForeName>John</ForeName>
    <Initials>J</Initials>
    <Affiliation>Department of Medicine, XYZ, NY USA; The Stony Brook Cancer Center, Stony Brook, NY 
11794, USA.</Affiliation>  
</Author>
```

However it has changed Affiliation to a multiple node

```
<Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ForeName>John</ForeName>
    <Initials>J</Initials>
    <AffiliationInfo> 
        <Affiliation>Department of Medicine, XYZ, NY USA; </Affiliation> 
    </AffiliationInfo>
    <AffiliationInfo>
        <Affiliation>The Stony Brook Cancer Center, Stony Brook, NY 11794, USA.</Affiliation>  ​
   ​</AffiliationInfo>
​</Author>
```

My question is how can I change my code to concatenate all of the Affiliations and add it to my insert?

Comment: When you say `concatenate` how would you like it? A single value, with commas in between each, something else?

Comment: A single value - yes but not a comma, since that will be in the Affiliation string but maybe a double bar || between them so it can be saved to a single field but split apart in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

The main change is instead of this line:

```
nref.value('Affiliation[1]','varchar(max)') Affiliation
```

it will be as follows:

```
nref.query('data(AffiliationInfo/Affiliation/text())').value('.','varchar(max)') Affiliation
```

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Author ValidYN="Y">
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <Initials>J</Initials>
    <AffiliationInfo>
        <Affiliation>Department of Medicine, XYZ, NY USA;</Affiliation>
    </AffiliationInfo>
    <AffiliationInfo>
        <Affiliation>The Stony Brook Cancer Center, Stony Brook, NY 11794, USA.</Affiliation>​
   ​</AffiliationInfo>
</Author>';

SELECT nref.value('@ValidYN','varchar(max)') AS ValidYN
    , nref.value('(LastName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
    , nref.value('(FirstName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
    , nref.value('(ForeName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS ForeName
    , nref.value('(Suffix/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS Suffix
    , nref.value('(Initials/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS Initials
    , nref.query('data(AffiliationInfo/Affiliation/text())').value('.','varchar(max)') AS Affiliation
FROM @xml.nodes('/Author') AS t(nref);
```

**SQL #2**

```
SELECT nref.value('@ValidYN','varchar(max)') AS ValidYN
    , nref.value('(LastName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
    , nref.value('(FirstName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
    , nref.value('(ForeName/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS ForeName
    , nref.value('(Suffix/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS Suffix
    , nref.value('(Initials/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS Initials
    , nref.query('
        for $r in AffiliationInfo/Affiliation/text()
        let $token := concat("[", $r, "]")
        return $token
        ').value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')AS Affiliation
FROM @xml.nodes('/Author') AS t(nref);
```

Comment: `.value('text()[1]'` is faster than `.`

Comment: The solution works great and is just what I asked for but I have a question.  Is it possible to put something between the between the concatenated strings?  Like || ?

Comment: I will try .value('text()[1]' also-- Thank you

Comment: @user1314159 You could change the `.query` to `...query(concat(data(AffiliationInfo/Affiliation/text()), "||")).value...`

Comment: @user1314159, I added to the answer **SQL #2** section. Check it out.

Comment: Thank You-  stackoverflow always have folks with great answers.  This is perfect

Comment: @user1314159, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote the suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali